# jquery submit doesn't submit the form

Tags: jquery

I don't want to use input type="image" or input type="submit". Was trying to use img html tag as submit button when it's clicked.  The click event on img tag and submit event on form works but the form is not getting submitted. Have the below HTML code

```
<form id="srch_id_form" name="srch_form" method="post" action="http://phbtxt.com.au:8080/cgi-bin/testpost.cgi" > 
    <img id="srch_id_submitform" src="update.png" />
</form>
```

Pasted the jquery code below.  I get the alert box "form is submitting" when the image is clicked but the form is not getting submitted.

```
$("#srch_id_submitform").click(function(){
    $("#srch_id_form").submit();
});

$("#srch_id_form").submit(function(){
    alert('Form is submitting');
    return true;
});
```

Comment: _"I don't want to use input type="image" or input type='submit'."_. Why not?

Comment: Can you try remove return true; and see what it happens? Your code seems fine but i didn't see any example in API documentation with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Difference between jQuery selector and DOM element**: a jQuery selector is a wrapper for a collection of DOM elements. If you call a function on a jquery selector, the called function is a jQuery function. If you need to call a function on a DOM element, you have to access the DOM element which is inside the jQuery collection, and call the function from it. To do this you use `get(index)`, where index is the index of the element inside the jQuery collection. If your jQuery selector only has one element, `.get(0)` is the DOM element.

`submit()` is 2 very different things:

- in jQuery, it's an event, which is normally triggered when a form is submitted (i.e. normally, when a form is submitted, this event is triggered, and you can do something if you have defined a handler for it). If you call `.submit()` in jQuery, it will trigger all the handlers for this event... but it won't submit the form.
- in a DOM element, it only exists for `form` elements, and is a method that submits the form

You don't have to trigger the [submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit) event, but to call the [submit()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp) method of the form DOM element.

To do so, don't use the jQuery selector, but the DOM form element itself:

`$("#srch_id_form").get(0).submit();`

[get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns the DOM element from a jQuery selector.

Note: when you use an element as an `img` to trigger an action it's very advisable to give visual clues to the user. You can do this using css `cursor` style, and change the style somewhat in the `:hover` state (pseudo-class) properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now.  why it's not working with the jquery selector?  what's the difference between the selector and form element when submit function is called.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation and your time.  I had accepted your answer.